# Is there a problem to use a random `output.uniqueName` in Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have just encountered an issue in which two Webpack 5 instances were conflicting in my page. I finally discovered that both were using the same `output.uniqueName`.

From [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputuniquename):

> #### output.uniqueName
>
> `string`
>
> A unique name of the webpack build to avoid multiple webpack runtimes to conflict when using globals. It defaults to `output.library` name or the package name from `package.json` in the context, if both aren't found, it is set to an `''`.
>
> `output.uniqueName` will be used to generate unique globals for:
>
> - `output.chunkLoadingGlobal`

Changing one of them manually fixed my issue.

However, I am looking for a more automated solution, since I will have lots of projects, and I don't want to manually keep track of this and risk conflicts.

My question: is there anything wrong in assigning a random string to `output.uniqueName` in the webpack config, like shown below? Of course, this name will change on different executions of the same project, but is this a problem?

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    uniqueName: generateRandomString(),
    // ...
  },
};
```